# Stop values from being entered into database python sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

How would I stop sqlite3 from adding the same exact values into a table if it is the exact same but otherwise add it? I'm totaly new to sqlite and don't know how to do this.

Comment: When you say 'same exact values' do you mean complete rows, or just values?  Also, do you really care if you have duplicate values when you can select using DISTINCT and get a single response?

Comment: @theodox values, like if i have ("bob","1") I don't want another ("bob","1")

Answer (score 1):

When you create the table, specify a [`unique` constraint](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#table-constraint):

```
create table foo ( name varchar, id integer, unique ( name, id) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define your table as @Robᵩ answered.

If you don't want, however, change an existing table definition - in SQLite you are very limited in `ALTER TABLE`, you can create a unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX foo_idx ON foo (name, id);
```

Note you are not allowed to create this index until you remove all duplicates.